# How to send Email with Letter Template Using suite script

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to send an email using suitescript2 i am trying to attach the the Letter template programaticaly.  Is there any way attach my custom letter template?

```
   function templatemerge() {
     var myMergeResult = render.mergeEmail({
templateId: 12,
entity: {
    type: 'customer',
    id: 31921
    },
recipient: {
    type: 'customer',
    id: 31921
    },
supportCaseId: 'NULL',
transactionId: 'NULL',
customRecord: 'custrecordid'
});
    }
    templatemerge();



    function sendEmailWithAttachement() {
    var newId =  context.newRecord;
        var emailbody = 'attachment';
        var senderId = -5;
        var recipientEmail = 'red@imi.com';

        email.send({
           author: senderId,
            recipients: recipientEmail,
            subject: 'Item Fulfillments',
            body: emailbody
        });
    }
    sendEmailWithAttachement();
```

Comment: What did you try so far?
Please add some code or describe your attempts

Comment: this looks like you just pasted in some random samples from the Netsuite help. If you actually follow the help there are several complete examples under N/render and N/email. If you read those and get an understanding of what is going on you'd be better placed to ask meaningful questions using the right (Netsuite oriented) terms.

Answer (score 2):

If, by letter template, you mean email template.  Here is a basic idea (I pulled that part from a larger script file that I am using) of how to do it.

```
var emailTemp4=nlapiLoadRecord('emailtemplate',emailTempID4); 
var emailSubj4=emailTemp4.getFieldValue('subject');
var emailBody4=emailTemp4.getFieldValue('content');
var renderer4=nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer();
renderer4.setTemplate(emailSubj4);
renderSubj4=renderer4.renderToString();
renderer4.setTemplate(emailBody4);
renderBody4=renderer4.renderToString();

nlapiSendEmail(-4,'RecipientEmail@domain.com',renderSubj4,renderBody4,null,null);
```

Comment: You should set the source record for the renderer if you want the content to be merged with the record data.

Comment: I mean letter template

Comment: Why do you want to use latter template for sending email?
For emails you should use email template.

Comment: @E56, okay, just thought I'd post that in case it could help.  I can delete the comment if it is of no help to you (just let me know).